# Php get_object_vars called for child class not working

Tags: php

I don't know if I have seriously misunderstood concept of OOP or I am implementing it wrong here. Can please somebody explain what I am doing wrong here

```
<?php

class my {
    public function myName(){
        return get_class($this);   
    }
    public function toArray() {
        $retArray=array();
        $class_vars = get_object_vars($this);

        foreach ($class_vars as $name => $value) {
           $retArray[$name]=$value;
        }
        return $retArray;
    }
}
class you extends my {
    private $yoo;
    public function __construct($var1) {
        $this->yoo=$var1;
    }
}
$objectYou = new you("I am pri");
echo '<pre>';
echo $objectYou->myName();
echo '<br>';
print_r($objectYou->toArray());
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

> Output is:
>
> you
>
> Array ( )

what I want here is to have super class `my` which has a function `toArray` to convert object to array. Now all the classes which extend this class should inherit this function and can use it. but here calling toArray on `objectYou` is returning empty array. At the same time calling `myName` on `objectYou` is showing name of child class.

Comment: Try making `$yoo` in `class you` as `protected` instead of `private`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only property (`$yoo`) is private, and thus not accessible from `my`, where toArray() is defined.

Comment: yes, get_object_vars() gets the ACCESSIBLE (and non-static) properties of the given object according to scope. See doc http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php